How to get better video/graphic performance with virt-manager for a Windows 10 guest?
After 2 weeks of trying and configuring, I managed to set up a Windows 10 virtual machine (as guest) with virt-manager on Ubuntu 24.04 (the host).
For my job, it is mandatory to use a CAE/CAD programm that only runs on Windows. It's a 2D programm so I don't need 3D acceleration but I need high resolution (4K for the guest and the host).
At this resolution (3840x2160 px), the mouse feedback in the guest is something slow. VMware provides a much more direct feeling but I do not want to use VMware anymore because of proprietary code.
In virt-manager, the display uses a SPICE-server and the video driver is QXL configured with these xml settings:
ram="524288" vram="524288" vgamem="131072"
Despite these high values for the video settings, everything related to graphic behaviour in the guest is something slow (useable but laggy). Yes, I've already installed the guest virtio driver from the Fedora project and yes, the virtual video card in Windows uses the QXL driver and yes, the laptop is powerfull enough to get everything smooth (AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS with integrated Radeon 780M, 32 GB RAM).
My question:
Is there any other way to speed up the graphic behavior in the Windows 10 guest?
